# Why it couldn't create my log file in case errors in Jython

Tags: redirect, jython

I don't undesrtand why this command desn't work

```
import os           
cmd = "ls 2>errors.log"   
retcode = os.system(cmd)   
if retcode > 1 :            
 raise "Fatal ListError (%d)" % retcode, "Erreur de split"
```

It coudn't redirect errors into erros.log. In case I don't have any error in my command At least it mus create the emty file errors.log

Comment: Your code worked for me in jython2.7b2.  Which version of Jython are you using?

Comment: @DavidCharles thank you so much for your comment I will check the version of Jython using then I will back to you
tell me please do you any idea instead of mine (ls 2>errors.log) of how can I redirect errors of my script into errors.log file